# Generate PDF with wkhtmltopdf after batch finished

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I would like to generate a pdf with wkhtmltopdf at the end of my batch.

I integrate the generation in the callback function but it does not offer me the download of the file

This is my finished function:

```
function csm_generate_pdf_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  $message = 'some errors';

  if ($success) {
    if (($library = libraries_load('phpwkhtmltopdf')) && !empty($library['loaded'])) {
      $pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf();
      $html = $results['data'];
      $start = $results['start'];
      $end = $results['end'];
      $pdf->addPage( $html );

      $filename = 'document_'.$start.'_'.$end.'.pdf';

      $pdf->send($filename);

      $message = 'Generation PDF ok';
    }
  }
  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

Comment: Does this code work when using it outside of batch?

Comment: Yes it works outside

Answer (score 1):

The Finish function runs in the background and you can't return file there, the solution for your case is redirected to another page and create and return pdf file there.

something like `drupal_goto('your_custom_url_to_generate');`

Comment: I try to add drupal_goto($path) with $path = '/generate/'.$start.'/'.$end;

it works, my file is downloaded, but the progress bar is stuck

Comment: When you redirect to a download, there is no change to the current page HTML. I would create a page with a download link in it, redirect to that and use some JS on the page to trigger the download automatically.

Comment: @Kipmag,  have you cleared the cache? maybe you need do some more action after  downloading

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache, but nothing

Comment: @Kipmag what if you redirect to another page after that?

Comment: @YusefMohamadi I add drupal_goto() at the end of my new function, after $pdf->send($filename), but now I am redirected but the file is no longer downloaded

Comment: @Kipmag , another suggestion, in the first `drupal_goto`, use `return drupal_goto(`